# facebook style layout question

Tags: css, blueprint-css

I am trying to emulate this simple layout :

```
_______________________________________
|____header___________________________|
     |                           |
     |                           | 
     | Blueprint Container       | 
     |                           | 
     |                           |
     |                           |
     |                           |
     |                           |
_____|___________________________|_____
|__footer______________________________|
```

Where

1. the header and footer stretch across the width of the page
2. header always stays at the top
3. footer sticks to the bottom
4. the blueprint container is a fixed width container and everything inside it is managed using blueprint.

What's the best to way to accomplished this. The challenge is my weak layout skills and understanding how to make the headers/footer fluid so that they always stretch but the container stays fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way would be to use CSS. I have uploaded some samples at http://www.4shared.com/file/zk1Sv21F/Facebook-Style_Bar.html
Also take a look at http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: It seems if the content portion is using Blueprint and the footer is done the way you have done in sample1..the context kinda gets lost behind the footer i.e. the footer sticks to the bottom and the bottom of the content gets hidden behind it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `position:fixed; width:100%; height:100px;` for the top and bottom divs. For the central one: `position:relative; margin:100px auto; width:1000px;`.